# Rails Database design: Composition, Sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sorting, model

In my Rails database for a Residents Association, I have User, Plot and House models. (empty Plots, Plots with one or more Houses, where owners or tenants live). From a database perspective I will need various relationships e.g.

- PlotHouse - house_id on a plot_id
- PlotOwnership - user_id owns plot_id
- HouseOwnership - user_id owns only the house_id but not the plot
- Rental - user_id rents house_id
- Relatives - Owner's or Tenant's relations

From a functional and user interface perspective, I need Member model with different roles - PlotOwners, HouseOwners, Tenants, Owner's Relatives, Tenant's relatives. I can do that with the existing models and relationships.

Problem: While displaying say, Residents, I cannot sort them on any one of User or House attribues since they come from different tables. If I create a Member model with columns from User, Plot, House models I would be duplicating the columns and hence risk inconsistency in the db.

I have CS background, but not production level database design, Rails or otherwise. Since the members data is required frequently, is it reasonable to duplicate these columns as long as I can enforce integrity in the system? Are there any other alternatives other than sorting the data in memory?

I see Members of different roles as reports but they need to be persisted since they are needed frequently and hence duplication for viewing, but basic models of User/Plot/Model without duplication for admins seems to be the way. Is there a gap in my understanding?

- Jayawanth

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with four models.

1. User (id, other columns)
2. Plot (id, other columns)
3. House (id, plot_id, other columns)
4. UserAssociation/some intuitive name for relating users to plot/house (id, user_id, associable_id, associable_type, role)

You can use [Polymorphic Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) to associate your user to plots and houses from only one model. Below are the association you would need.

```
class User < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :user_associations
  has_many :plots, :through => :user_associations, :source => :associable, :source_type => 'Plot'
  has_many :houses, :through => :user_associations, :source => :associable, :source_type => 'House'
end

class Plot < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :houses
  has_many :user_associations, :as => :associable
  has_many :users, :through => :user_associations
end

class House < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :plot
  has_many :user_associations, :as => :associable
  has_many :users, :through => :user_associations
end

class UserAssociation < ActiveRecord:Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :associable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Comment: The issue for me is not optimizing associations. As stated in my original post, when data is fetched from two different tables and displayed in a view, my understanding is I cannot sort on any of the displayed columns. Should I duplicate house details to allow sorting on a column in say, the Residents Table?